# C# socket image transfer: file sometimes partially transferred

Tags: c#, php, sockets

**Problem**

I have `PHP` client which sends a image file to a `C#` **socket server**.  My problem is about *30%* of the time the **file is partially transferred** and stops.

**PHP END** ->

```
$file = file_get_contents('a.bmp');
socket_write($socket,$file);
```

**C# END** ->

```
 int l= Socket.Receive(buffer, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
  //create the file using a file stream
```

How can I always transfer the full file without intermediate states?  And why does it happen?

Comment: How large is the file your trying to send?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for [Socket.Receive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3xtz6a5.aspx):

> If you are using a connection-oriented Socket, the Receive method will read **as much data as is available, up to the number of bytes specified by the size parameter**. If the remote host shuts down the Socket connection with the Shutdown method, and all available data has been received, the Receive method will complete immediately and return zero bytes.

This means you may get **less** than the total amount.  This is just the way sockets work.

So if if you get a partial read, you should call `Socket.Receive` again.  You can use the overload of `Socket.Receive` to continue reading into the same buffer.

Here is an article that shows how "keep reading" until you get what you want:

- [Socket Send and Receive](http://www.csharp-examples.net/socket-send-receive/)

If you don't know how big the data is, you must keep reading until `Socket.Receive` returns zero.

Comment: hi rick im using `int l= Socket.Receive(buffer, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);`   *int l* will specify transferred file size and im creating as the length of `l` ... this happens few times :-s

Comment: the idea is to stop receiving, and start again every 1000 bytes or so, until the socket receive returns zero, this allows you to receive data indefinitely (you should put a cap on this though, so nobody can ddos your server by feeding you data forever).

Comment: @Sudantha: Even if you know the length, sockets can give you the data in pieces.  Use the `Receive` method in the link I gave to reassemble the pieces into the known size.

Comment: yea thats true ! programmaticly how i stop this ?

Comment: And a very similar argument applies on the sending side also - `socket_write` returns the number of bytes written, which again may not match the number of bytes that you requested to send - you need loops on both the sending and receiving ends.

Comment: @Sudantha: There is no option to stop it; you have to **cope** with it.

Comment: All data will be broken up at max, the MTU of the total packets. You always have to loop to read data.  This is why network protocols will sometimes precede the data with a size or succeed with an "End of Packet" structure.  This is how you know when to stop in your loop.

Comment: it's better to have something like this: `byteRead += Socket.Receive(buffer, byteRead, buffer.Length- byteRead, SocketFlags.None);` so the second time, it will start where it left in the receive buffer.  (best to split this, because you want to check if it returns 0)